# Use an existing invoice if one exists, else create one

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Here are the requirements:

- If `initial_invoice?` is `false`, `existing_invoice` always exists.
- If `initial_invoice?` is `true` and `existing_invoice` exists, I'd love to use the `existing_invoice`.

I'd love to refactor this code.

```
 existing_invoice = find_existing_invoice(invoice_obj[:id])
   invoice = if !initial_invoice?(invoice_obj) || existing_invoice.present?
                existing_invoice
              else
                ac = Account.find_by(stripe_customer_id: invoice_obj[:customer])
                create_initial_invoice(invoice_obj, ac)
              end

  private

  def find_existing_invoice(id)
    Invoice.find_by(stripe_invoice_id: id)
  end

  def initial_invoice?(invoice_obj)
    sub_id = invoice_obj[:subscription]
    return false if sub_id.nil?

    sub = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(sub_id)
    return false unless invoice_obj[:period_start] == sub[:created]
    true
  end
```

**update**

```
invoice = if initial_invoice?(invoice_obj)
            return existing_invoice if existing_invoice.present?

            ac = Account.find_by(stripe_customer_id: invoice_obj[:customer])
            create_initial_invoice(invoice_obj, ac)
          else
            existing_invoice
          end
```

Comment: `existing_invoice.present?` - is `existing_invoice` potentially nil?  ... Can `initial_invoice?` be in the Invoice class so you can do this: `existing_invoice.initial?` ...  Should the requirement "... `existing_invoice` always exists" be explicitly checked up front; and then handle as an error if not?  ...  Is `create_initial_invoice` different, really, from creating any invoice? Why the "special" method? If the invoice class had a `initial?` property then may not need special methods, only  `find_invoice` and `create_invoice`. Might DRY up some code and make client (caller) code simpler.

Comment: @radarbob Thanks for the advice. This is a Webhook handler. So depending on the values, I need to execute differently. (create invoice and create invoice_items)

Comment: `Invoice.find_by` finds initial invoices, and `Account.find_by` finds all other invoices? Yes?  I'd write the top-level logic around this to make the difference clear, like, "IF initial_invoice then create-or-find initial-invoice ELSE create-or-find not-initial-invoice   END." That emphasizes what I think is the real difference.  Then checking/validating those requirements, if needed, are in proper context of the particular "create-or-find" method. In any case it really troubles me that I need a second object to tell me if I'm an initial_invoice. I should know that for myself.

Comment: updated! Is this more obvious? It would be more appreciate if you could post your code.

Comment: I hear ya dude. We come to StackExchange for answers.  I was past my beddy-bye time last night and I'm home sick today.  You're right that this code needs work; it also needs some thought. I did not want to simply regurgitate a half-ass an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The refactor goal was to make clear the logic for getting an invoice.

- THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT POINT: Original code tells me there are 2 kinds of invoices so I knew I wanted a "if" that stated very simply and high level the logic for deciding which. So I wrote that and worked all the rest of the code around it.
- Moving code into the `get_xxx` methods I saw that fetching the existing invoice was in both methods.
- The above had me realize that no matter what, we use an pre-existing invoice if it's there. So I pulled that line out and put it at the top. Now it is obvious what's really going on.
- I renamed `invoice_obj` because that sounds like it's an invoice too. But it's not. Its properties are used for fetching an actual invoice. So I thought of `invoice_obj` as `metadata` of a real invoice.
- Make both "if" branches the same "level of abstraction". I'm trying to express that there are 2 kinds of invoices. I'm hiding the detail code that actually does it - that's a different level of detail.

I want it to say this:

```
if ...
  get_initial_invoice(metadata)
else
  get_invoice(metadata)
```

and not this:

```
if ...
  get_initial_invoice(metadata)
else
  Invoice.find_by(metadata[:id])
```

---

**Refactored Code**

```
 return existing_invoice if existing_invoice.present?

 invoice = nil

 if initial_invoice?(invoice_metadata)
    invoice = get_initial_invoice(invoice_metadata)
 else
    invoice = get_invoice(invoice_metadata)
 end

 return invoice


 private

 def get_initial_invoice(invoice_metadata)   
    ac = Account.find_by(stripe_customer_id: invoice_metadata[:customer])
    create_initial_invoice(invoice_metadata, ac)
 end

 def get_invoice(invoice_metadata)
    return Invoice.find_by(invoice_metadata[:id])
 end

 def initial_invoice?(invoice_metadata)
   return false if invoice_metadata[:subscription].nil?

   sub = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(invoice_metadata[:subscription])
   invoice_metadata[:period_start] == sub[:created] ? true : false
 end
```